# Components returned from .map() not loading in DOM

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to load some components into the DOM after a `get` call is made. The console confirms that the components are loaded into the variable, but the DOM doesn't update. Is there a syntax problem

```
const Blog: FC<BlogProps> = ({title, url}): ReactElement => {
    let response = [];
    let Posts = [];
    const {isDarkMode} = useContext(ThemeContext);
    function fetchBlogs(){
        let url = url;
        let count = 30;
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/api/grabIt',
            data: {
                url: url,
                count: count
            }
        })
            .then(function (res) {
                response = res.data.response;
                Posts = response.map(async function (item, i) {
                   return (<li><Post category={item.type} title={item.title} author={item.by} image={item.url} link={item.url} key={i}/></li>)
                })
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            });
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <Button buttonColor={!!isDarkMode}
                        onClick={fetchBlogs}
                >FETCH</Button>
                <ul>
                    {Posts}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </>
    )
};

export default Blog
```

I have also tried just creating an array thats defined when the component is loaded (instead of after), and the DOM still doesnt update. I just get an empty `<ul>`

Comment: Why is the function inside `map` async? It returns a promise, not a component instance.

Comment: Posts is just a variable, has no connection to component state, React does not know that it needs to rerender. change Posts to use React.useState

Comment: You could add the mapping logic inside the return and use states for updatting it. Any reason to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const Blog: FC<BlogProps> = ({ title, url }): ReactElement => {
    let response = [];
    const { isDarkMode } = useContext(ThemeContext);
    const [list, setList] = React.useState([]);
    function fetchBlogs() {
        let url = url;
        let count = 30;
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/api/grabIt',
            data: {
                url: url,
                count: count
            }
        })
            .then(function (res) {
                setList(res.data.response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            });
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <Button buttonColor={!!isDarkMode}
                    onClick={fetchBlogs}
                >FETCH</Button>
                <ul>
                    {list.map((item, i) => {
                        return <li key={`row-${i}`}>
                            <Post category={item.type} title={item.title} author={item.by} image={item.url} link={item.url} key={i} />
                        </li>;
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </>
    )
};

export default Blog
```

Answer (score 1):

First, when generating multiple tags, you should add the `key` to the root element you return.

To get your list loaded, you need to use `useState` for your Posts array.

Answer (score 1):

`Posts` is a regular array, and not reactive, in the React sense. Changing it won't trigger a re-render. Use `useState` to make it a reactive variable. You also should be `map`ping over the response synchronously, and it's not really necessary to create the components here. Instead do this in the return statement:

```
const Blog: FC<BlogProps> = ({title, url}): ReactElement => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = React.useState([]);
  const {isDarkMode} = useContext(ThemeContext);

  function fetchBlogs() {
    axios({
      method: 'post',
        url: '/api/grabIt',
        data: { url, count: 30 }
      })
        .then(function (res) {
           if (res.data.response) {
             setPosts(res.data.response);
           }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        });
    }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Button
          buttonColor={!!isDarkMode}
          onClick={fetchBlogs}
        >
          FETCH
        </Button>
        <ul>
          {posts.map((post, i) => (
            <li key={i}>
              <Post
                category={post.type}
                title={post.title}
                author={post.by}
                image={post.url}
                link={post.url} 
               />
            </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  )
};

export default Blog;
```